# List a files in python and save it

Tags: python, filesystems, directory

I can't save this output, maybe someone have the solution. I'm listing a directory and some singles files. But when I save the output just catch the directory files, and Not the singles files. 
My code:

```
import os
tosave = open('/tmp/list','ab')
thesource = ["/etc/ssh","/var/log/syslog","/etc/hosts"]
for f in thesource:
    print f
    for top, dirs, files in os.walk(f):
        for nm in files:
            print os.path.join(top, nm)
            try:
                tosave.write(top+nm+'\n')
            finally:
                tosave.close
```

I saw in the console all files and directory, but in the saved list, just ssh files. Why didn't save syslog and hosts too?

Thank you !!

Comment: Are you just trying to save the **name** of the files in those directories? i.e. moduli ssh_config sshd_config

Comment: nop I'm trying to save all abosolute path in a txt file. but I found another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In case you missed the `()` at `tosave.close` while pasting: (otherwise check [harsh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8462202/1091453))*

The `finally` is wrong here. The code in `finally` will be executed after the `try` block, so after the first execution of `tosave.write(top+nm+'\n')` the file will be closed because of `tosave.close()`.

Possibly you intended to use `except`:

```
            # snip
            try:
                tosave.write(top+nm+'\n')
            except:
                tosave.close()
```

---

Edit: To answer your comment, you want the last line to be the same as the print statement:

```
                tosave.write(os.path.join(top, nm) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding `tosave.flush()` at the end. It does cause problems sometimes. Sometimes, a flush call is required to empty the contents of the buffer into the file.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works for you

```
import os
tosave = open('/tmp/list','ab')
thesource = ["/etc/ssh","/var/log/syslog","/etc/hosts"]
for f in thesource:
    if os.path.isdir(f):
        for top, dirs, files in os.walk(f):
            for nm in files:
                try:
                    tosave.write(top+nm+'\n')
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        tosave.write(f+'\n')
to.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

With all your help I found a solution and it's working. I share it.

```
tosave = open('/tmp/list','ab')
    thesource = ["/etc/ssh","/var/log/syslog","/etc/hosts"]
for f in thesource:
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        print f
        tosave.write(f+'\n')
    else:
        for top, dirs, files in os.walk(f):
            for nm in files:
                print os.path.join(top, nm)
                tosave.write(top+nm+'\n')
```

Thank you all for your help !!!

Comment: Now I found another problems, if I put another directory with a lot a subdirectories like /et/apache2/ I lose the "/" in the recursive action

/etc/apache/sites-avaibletest.vhost when the right will be /etc/apache/sites-avaible/test.vhost ufff too complicate !!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because you're opening the file in append mode (the `'a'`) and then looking at its beginning? Look at its end - you might see your new files listed there.

In append mode, each time the script runs it *appends* its output to the file. Usually what one wants is just the write mode (`'w'` instead of `'a'`), which overwrites the file each time.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `close()` at the end of the script.

Otherwise it will close the file after the first step in the loop, making the file unwritable.